# Possible to use Windows workstation session to authenticate apache httpd user?

Tags: php, apache, authentication, windows-authentication

Is it possible to use a Windows session to authenticate a user so that my Apache httpd/PHP web application won't require additional authentication?  I would want to know from the Windows session who the user is so I can restrict functions on a per user basis, but I don't want the user to have to log in again.

I see some articles about using LDAP from Apache, but it's not clear to me if that just lets me verify the login information after requesting credentials or if it allows me to make the login seamless/invisible...

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for is basically impossible (or almost impossible). You want your Apache to be able to access Windows session. Apache speaks through HTTP protocol only. Browser in your Windows is the one who speaks HTTP. There nothing in HTTP what can instruct your browser to ask Windows session user name. The only way around it to have JS embedded in your page. But again your browser will prohibit your page from getting this information. Why? Because it is ENORMOUS SECURITY THREAT!

There nothing in HTTP request from a browser what can tie it up with particular Windows session and hence it cannot be done.

Comment: Actually, this happens regularly with IIS on our intranet.  Take a look at [Integrated Windows Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication).  I just don't know if the same is possible with Apache because the components won't play nice...

Comment: IWA is proprietary stuff from M$ (and I personally consider as dirty hack around). There's SSPI Apache module for Windows in existence - it may work for you. But plain vanilla Apache running under Linux cannot run this. As I said: it is almost impossible. Whatever solution you will find will require backstage authentication. Meaning Apache would need to seek authentication details not through HTTP: HTTP protocol just doesn't have it.